# Find and Replace Text with Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, replace, find

I am new to Prototype and was wondering how to simply "find" some text in a class/ID and "replace" this text.

My html is like this:

```
<div id="test">
  <a href="/test">test</a>
  <a href="/test2">test2</a>
  <a href="/test3">test3</a>
  <a href="/test4">test4</a>
</div>
```

And I am trying to replace the "test" in between the `<a>` tags for the first `<a>` with the word `"success"` and the second `<a>` with `"success2"`. So it would look like

```
<div id="test">
      <a href="/test">Login</a>
      <a href="/test2">Register</a>
      <a href="/test3">Bla</a>
      <a href="/test4">Logout</a>
    </div>
```

Any ideas how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different approach using getElementsByTagName

```
var r=[['Login','success'],['Register','donkey'],['Bla','...'],['Logout','Are you sure?']];
var x=document.getElementById("test");
var a=x.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i in a){
    a[i].innerHTML=a[i].innerHTML.replace(r[i][0],r[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With DOM

```
var x=document.getElementById("test");
for(var i in x.childNodes){
    if(x.childNodes[i].tagName=='A'){
        x.childNodes[i].innerHTML=x.childNodes[i].innerHTML.replace(/test/,'success');
    }
}
```

Comment: hey s.mark - thanks a lot. this changes the "first" <a> but how would I go about changing the 2nd or 3rd with different text ? [thanks so much again!]

Comment: um, its for both actually, its looping all the childNodes, which include both a tag.

Comment: ah :) if the word in the 2nd <a> isn't "success" how would i do it ? i.e. if it was "success" and "donkey" for example ?

Comment: 2nd and 3rd with different text? you may need to count it 1st, 2nd, 3rd inside the loop, and will probably need 3 `if` conditions for each.

Comment: so like this ?

if(x.childNodes[1].tagName=='A'){
        x.childNodes[1].innerHTML=x.childNodes[1].innerHTML.replace(/test/,'success');
    }

i edited html to show what i mean ? :)

Comment: Added another answer, since you need different approach